# render HTML with blade @foreach inside script tag

Tags: php, jquery, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a dropdown list. For particular option selected I want to render HTML with different data in view coming from the controller.

For this, I am writing script tag in view, then using blade foreach inside jQuery if condition then iterating HTML inside blade php. but its giving me error

```
userprofile:966 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

I am new to Laravel and still exploring, so wondering if it is even possible.
If it's not possible then how can I achieve this?

Here is my code

```
<script>
                        $(document).ready(function () {

                            if ($("#user_right").val() == 1)
                            {
                                @foreach ($user_alias_detail["a"] as $user)

                                        <div class="field">
                                            <input type="text" value="{{ $user->name }}">
                                        </div>
                                @endforeach
                            }
                            elseif ($("#user_right").val() == 2)
                            {
                                @foreach ($user_alias_detail["b"] as $user)

                            <div class="field">
                                <input type="text" value="{{ $user->name }}">
                            </div>
                                @endforeach
                            }
                        });
                    </script>
```

Comment: You should give us your `$user_alias_detail` so that we can make sure you are not `foreaching` the wrong attribute

Comment: "_Here is my code which is giving me error_" What error would that be? Can you paste that in your question? Also, I'm not sure why you use Javascript in there, this could probably be achieved with Blade alone.

Comment: You can't display pure `html` inside of a `script` tag, that's why you get an error.

Comment: Why even bother display html in javascript. WHy do you think jquery has $.load or $.get. Let php render the html and return it will requests. Append the result and done. Clean code

Answer (score 0):

to give you a complete answer I'd need to know where in your code all these elements should be displayed.

I'd use something like this. You convert your php array into a json array and 
use a (for .. in) loop to iterate through the json array. With jquery append, you insert html into a parent DOM Element.

```
<script>
var user_a = @json($user_alias_detail["a"]);
var user_b = @json($user_alias_detail["b"]);


       $(document).ready(function () {

                        if ($("#user_right").val() == 1)

                                for(var user in user_a) {
                                // container div is the wrapper element
                                $(".container-div").append('<div class="field">
                                    <input type="text" value="'+user.name+'">
                                </div>');
                            }
                    }
                    elseif ($("#user_right").val() == 2)
                    {

                            for(var user in user_b) {
                                // container div is the wrapper element
                                $(".container-div").append('<div class="field">
                                    <input type="text" value="'+user.name+'">
                                </div>');
                            }
                    }
                });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this piece of code. i took time in writing it for you. you can modify it to suite your need. Thank you.

```
//form blade

<div class="form-group">
   <label class="control-label">Select Value <span style="color:red">*</span></label>

   <select class="form-control" id="user_right" name="user_right" required>  
      <option value="">--Select--</option>             
      <option value="1"{{(old('user_right')=='1')? "selected"  : ""}}>One</option>
      <option value="2"{{(old('user_right')=='2')? "selected"  : ""}}>Two</option>
      <option value="3"{{(old('user_right')=='3')? "selected"  : ""}}>Three</option>

   </select>

</div>

<div class="form-group">
  @if($htmldata=='')
     <!--display nothing on page-->
  @else

   {{ $htmldata->recorddetails }}

  @elseif                                


</div>


//javascript code to fetch the item id
<script type="text/javascript">
            // When the document is ready
     $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#user_right").change(function(e){

       var value= e.target.value;

       if ("https:" == document.location.protocol) 
        {

        location.href="https://example.com/renderpage/"+value;
        } 
      else 
        {
        location.href="http://example.com/renderpage/"+value;
       }

    });

</script>


//route
Route::get('/loadpage','Controller@displayPage');
Route::get('/renderpage/{id}','Controller@displaydataonPage');


//controller to load page
public function displayPage()
   {  

      $data['htmldata']='';    
      return view('htmlpage', $htmldata);

   }

//controller to display data on page
public function displaydataonPage($id)
   {  
 $data['htmldata']=DB::table('table')->where('datavalue',$id)->orderby('rank','asc')->first();             
      return view('htmlpage', $htmldata);    
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

Use template literals ``

```
                 <script>
                    $(document).ready(function () {

                        if ($("#user_right").val() == 1)
                        {
                           `
                            @foreach ($user_alias_detail["a"] as $user)

                                    <div class="field">
                                        <input type="text" value="{{ $user->name }}">
                                    </div>
                            @endforeach
                           `
                        }
                        elseif ($("#user_right").val() == 2)
                        {
                          `
                            @foreach ($user_alias_detail["b"] as $user)

                        <div class="field">
                            <input type="text" value="{{ $user->name }}">
                        </div>
                            @endforeach
                          `
                        }
                    });
                </script>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals